# Does there exist a 'local' version of the Killing-Hopf theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In the book of John Lee, named 'Introduction to Riemannian manifolds', there is stated the Killing-Hopf theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $(M,g)$ be a complete, simply-connected Riemannian $n$-manifold with constant sectional curvature, $n \geq 2$. Then $M$ is isometric to one of the three model spaces $\mathbb{E}^n, S^n (R)$ and $H^n (R)$. Their sectional curvatures are resp. $K = 0, K= 1/R^2$ and $K = -1/R^2$.

Here $H^n (R)$ denotes hyperbolic space of radius $R$.

**Question:** I was wondering, is there also a 'local' version of this theorem, for example when we drop the condition of $M$ being complete? An adequate reference is desired.

Comment: Yes: if a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ has constant sectional curvature $\kappa$, then $(M,g)$ is locally isometric to $M_{\kappa}$, the complete simply connected manifold of constant sectional curvature $\kappa$. The proof is exactly the same as for the Killing-Hopf theorem: in a neighbourhood of any point, one can construct coordinates system realizing the isometry, namely, polar coordinates in an exponential chart.

Comment: I don't know what $H(\kappa)$ is. Can you please elaborate and provide a reference?

Comment: See the edited comment. Also, $H^n(R)$ is certainly not an hyperbolic space of **radius** $R$ as if it is complete, it as infinite diameter (and volume).